# In Django, how do I render fields of fields from a queryset in JSON when sending a response from an AJAX view?

Tags: json, django, serialization, django-queryset

I'm using Django 2 with Python 3.7.  In my view, I have this code for sending JSOn to an AJAX call ...

```
articlestat_query = ArticleStat.objects.get_stats()
...
data = {
    'articlestat': serializers.serialize('json', list(articlestat_query)),
    ...
}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

The query "articlestat_query" pulls models that look like this ...

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleStatManager()
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    score = models.FloatField(default=0, null=False)
```

The issue is when my JSON is generated, the "article" piece gets returned as "article" and its numeric primary key, e.g.

```
"article": 12345678
```

How do I configure my serialization so that the JSON of that field is rendered instead of its primary key.  IOW, the JSON would be

```
"article": {"title": "hello world", "author": "George Costanza" ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the best way is to use Django Rest Framework's serializers. Take a look at [ModelSeriazer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

In your case article will represented as another ModelSerializer, like:

```
class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('title', 'author'...)


class ArticleStatSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    article = ArticleSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ArticleStat
        fields = ('article', ...)


...
articlestat_query = ArticleStat.objects.get_stats().prefetch_related('article')
...
data = {
    'articlestat': ArticleStatSerializer(articlestat_query, many=True).data,
    ...
}
return JsonResponse(data)
```

DRF is absolute must have tool.

Comment: Thanks.  In what file is the "json_data = json.dumps(ArticleStatSerializer(instance).data)" line and how does that relate to the queryset of ArticleStat objects I'm returning?

Comment: @Dave I updated the answer. Don't forget to use prefetch_related in those cases

Comment: Hi @Andrey, The "fields = ('article', ...)" should be "fields = ['article', ...]", is that right?  I'm getting some errors when I use the parens.

Comment: @Dave usually it's not casing errors. What error did you get?

Comment: I forget the errors that I saw but if anyone else sees this and has similar errors, I seemed to get by using "[]" instead of "()" when defining the fields.